# Google Apps Script. How can I retrieve the URL of a html file located in my project?

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script I have a project containing a couple html files.
I have a script published as a web app who redirect the authenticated users according to the group they belong:

```
  if (groupA.hasUser(currentUser.getEmail())) {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('GroupA').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
} else {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('GroupB').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

In GroupA.html I want to make a hyperlink to a html file contained in my project, like `<a href="myInternalFileUrl">Click here </a>`

How can I get the reference of a html file within a Google Script Project?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the HTML files directly, they don't have their own URL's. When you publish your script, it has a single URL that all requests will be directed too.

To serve different html files, you can pass in a query string argument that indicates which file to display, then have your script load the appropriate file.

When a script is published, the doGet() function is called automatically.

for example, say you have a main page called default.html, and other pages you want the user to load in certain cases:

```
function doGet(e){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('default.html');

  if(e.parameter.page)
    html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(e.parameter.page);

  return html;
}
```

To access files other than default.html using this code, you would pass in a "?page=" query string on your url, with the filename after the =.

```
<a href="https://[SCRIPT URL HERE]?page=second_page.html">Click Here</a>
```

The link above, with [SCRIPT URL HERE] replaced by your actual script url, would display the html file named "second_page.html"

See:
   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Comment: You can also bind the query string  
`template.params = JSON.stringify(e)` 
And use it on the html  
`var queryString = JSON.parse('<?= params ?>');`